# India e-Visa Query

Tags: visas, india, e-visas

I'm planning on heading back to India next month. I already had an e-Visa issued in October which I used previously but it expires end of December so I'm applying for another.

The official website states "The passport should have at least two blank pages for stamping by the Immigration Officer." I have 4 blank pages in random locations in my passport but neither are consecutively blank, one beside the other.

Any insight into whether this will cause any problems?

Answer (score 6):

As said in the comments, to get an Indian E-Visa two blank pages are needed, but they do not have to be next to each other.

One page will be used for the visa itself, and other will be used for the entry stamp. As you have four pages left this will be fine.